# ruby: adding numbers and printing true when sums are 21

Tags: ruby, sum, splat

It's a simple problem given on rubeque.com: write a method that takes any number of integers and adds them to return true if the sum is 21. False otherwise. It tests the input with:

```
assert_equal twenty_one?(3, 4, 5, 6, 3), true
assert_equal twenty_one?(3, 11, 10), false
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
def twenty_one?(*nums)
  nums.inject(&:+)
end

if twenty_one? == 21 
  puts true
else 
  false
end
```

But I get the error message:

```
RuntimeError: The value '21' does not equal 'true'.
```

I'm really confused on how to fix this. Is it possible to put the if/else statement within the method? And sorry if this question is really basic. I'm new to programming.

Comment: when you write `if twenty_one? == 21` you are running `twenty_one?` with no arguments, which returns `nil`. And `nil` does not equal `21`. Also, you should know that is convention in Ruby that methods ending with a question mark shall only return booleans (`true` or `false`). Just to clarify a little bit ;-)

Comment: @CarlesJoveBuxeda My class name `Numerics` looks very _odd_. Can you suggest a good name? :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit I'll comment this on your anser, ok?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write your method as

```
def twenty_one?(*nums)
  nums.inject(&:+) == 21
end
```

Here is one little demo :-

```
require "minitest/autorun"

class Numerics
  def twenty_one?(*nums)
    nums.inject(&:+) == 21
  end
end

class TestNumerics < MiniTest::Test
  def setup
    @numeric = Numerics.new
  end

  def teardown
    @numeric = nil
  end

  def test_twenty_one?
    assert_equal @numeric.twenty_one?(3, 4, 5, 6, 3), true
    assert_equal @numeric.twenty_one?(3, 11, 10), false
  end
end
```

Let's run the tests :-

```
[arup@Ruby]$ ruby test/test_numerics.rb
Run options: --seed 61602

# Running:

.

Finished in 0.001332s, 750.9402 runs/s, 1501.8804 assertions/s.

1 runs, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
[arup@Ruby]$
```

In your method, it was returning `Fixnum` instance `21`, which you were trying to compare with `true`. That's why you got the error. If you look at the source of [`assert_equal`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_equal), you will find the comparisons between 2 objects which are the instances of the same class, otherwise it will throw the error you got.

**Note:** You of-course can write this `nums.inject(&:+)` as `nums.inject(:+)` too as Ruby allows this freedom in case of `#reduce/#inject` method particularly out of the box.

**Update**

[Carles Jove Buxeda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002853/ruby-adding-numbers-and-printing-true-when-sums-are-21/28002873?noredirect=1#comment44424190_28002873) gave one nice idea to design this problem. The idea is to put the methods inside the module, and then include it to test its methods:

```
require "minitest/autorun"

module Numerics
  def twenty_one?(*nums)
    nums.inject(:+) == 21
  end
end

class TestNumerics < MiniTest::Test
  include Numerics

  def test_twenty_one?
    assert_equal twenty_one?(3, 4, 5, 6, 3), true
    assert_equal twenty_one?(3, 11, 10), false
  end
end
```

Now if I run it :

```
arup_ruby$ ruby test/test_numerics.rb
Run options: --seed 1223

# Running:

.

Finished in 0.001067s, 937.2071 runs/s, 1874.4142 assertions/s.

1 runs, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
arup_ruby$
```

Very cool idea!

Comment: @ArupRakshit Hey Arup. Since it is just an example, I wouldn't worry much about the class name. However, if this was a real situation, I wouldn't want to make an instance of a class for this, specially if I need to check it often . So maybe `Numerics` could be a `module` that you include in your classes. Modules can be included in tests, too, since they're just regular classes.

Comment: @CarlesJoveBuxeda I use SO to help others and for personal learning as well :). And lots of thanks as you replied back to my comment. Could you show me a gist link if possible to show the approach you had in your mind. I am asking just to learn nice things, that I don't know yet.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Here you are: https://gist.github.com/carlesjove/948ff8b59ea60ca1dfe9

Comment: @CarlesJoveBuxeda Would you mind if I add it to my answer as an _update_ ? BTW, I have started to follow you on GitHub :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit No problem! In fact, if you think that it improves the answer, it's cool that you update it ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Arup's answer is great. I would suggest to make it a little more generic.

```
def twenty_one?(*nums)
  nums.inject(&:+) == 21
end

def compare_value_with_sum_of_nums?(value, *nums)
  nums.inject(&:+) == value
end
```

I am really bad with names. This made me think it would be pretty cool to combine your method name with metaprogramming and the gem [humanize](https://github.com/radar/humanize). You could then have dynamic method names and infer from the method name what value the sum should add up to. So you could have any comparison, like

MyAwesomeGem.three_thousand_and_twenty_four?(3000, 20, 4)

Would be fun to build!

:)